# how do I convert dyn dynamic external ip-address to ubuntu 13.04 internal ip-address

Tags: networking, 13.04, dynamic-ip

how do I convert dyn dynamic external ip-address  to ubuntu 13.04 internal ip-address

I have isc-dhcp-server apache2 dns ubuntu 13.04  netcomm 3G-sim card router

I am using ddclient to obtain the dyndns dynamic records - this comes up as my external ip-address - Ineed to convert this to an internal ip-address for apache2 and dhcp-server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your Netcom router, but the basic (and easy) route to follow is:

1. Let your router handle DHCP for your internal network addresses;
2. Assign your server a reserved static IP address in the router (within the IP range it distributes);
3. Open and forward any ports you want passed to the server in the router.

Dyn will handle the DNS resolution to your public-facing IP address and route requests for your domain. Dyn has reasonable [documentation](http://dyn.com/support/) on configurations for their services, which I would recommend reading through.